# Nextjs website deployed, but i cannot see anything on website

Tags: firebase, next.js, firebase-hosting

I am using nextjs for my project. Previously , when my website just contained static pages, at that time, firebase deployed it and I was able to see deployed pages on deployed link. But, after adding Server side rendering to website, it deployed the website, but I cannot see anything on it.
[image]

When I ran the app locally, I was able to see pages.

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "rurualco-customer",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "eslint \"src/**/*.{ts,tsx,md}\"",
    "ts": "tsc --noEmit --skipLibCheck",
    "checks": "yarn lint && yarn ts",
    "postinstall": "husky install"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@tanstack/react-table": "^8.9.1",
    "@types/node": "20.1.0",
    "@types/react": "18.2.6",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.59.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.59.2",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
    "aws-amplify": "^5.2.1",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "babel-plugin-inline-react-svg": "^2.0.2",
    "clsx": "^1.2.1",
    "cookies-next": "^2.1.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.30.0",
    "eslint": "8.40.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-typescript-sort-keys": "^2.3.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^12.1.0",
    "next": "13.4.1",
    "postcss": "8.4.23",
    "prettier": "^2.8.8",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.43.9",
    "tailwind-merge": "^1.12.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.2",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@svgr/webpack": "^8.0.1",
    "husky": "^8.0.0"
  }
}
```

firebase.json:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "source": ".",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "frameworksBackend": {
      "region": "us-west1"
    }
  }
}
```

.firebaserc

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "possible-fabric-320701"
  }
}
```

When I ran  , "firebase deploy --only functions hosting":

```
   Thank you for trying our early preview of Next.js support on Firebase Hosting.
   During the preview, support is best-effort and breaking changes can be expected. Proceed with caution.

   Documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/frameworks/nextjs
   File a bug: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/new?template=bug_report.md
   Submit a feature request: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/new?template=feature_request.md

   We'd love to learn from you. Express your interest in helping us shape the future of Firebase Hosting: https://goo.gle/41enW5X

- info Loaded env from /home/manas/techwondoe/ruralco-customer-portal/.env
- info Checking validity of types  
- info Disabled SWC as replacement for Babel because of custom Babel configuration ".babelrc" https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/swc-disabled
- info Using external babel configuration from /home/manas/techwondoe/ruralco-customer-portal/.babelrc
- info Creating an optimized production build  
- info Compiled successfully
- info Collecting page data  
- info Finalizing page optimization  

Route (pages)                              Size     First Load JS
┌ λ /                                      262 B           164 kB
├   /_app                                  0 B             164 kB
├ λ /404                                   263 B           164 kB
├ λ /api/mock                              0 B             164 kB
├ λ /api/statement                         0 B             164 kB
├ λ /auth/confirm-sign-up                  2.08 kB         220 kB
├ λ /auth/forgot-pass                      2.14 kB         220 kB
├ λ /auth/login                            2.25 kB         220 kB
├ λ /auth/reset-pass                       1.8 kB          220 kB
├ λ /auth/sign-up                          2.03 kB         220 kB
└ λ /dashboard                             5.52 kB         223 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all              167 kB
  ├ chunks/framework-2c79e2a64abdb08b.js   45.2 kB
  ├ chunks/main-8c5a7bca48678ec0.js        36.3 kB
  ├ chunks/pages/_app-c7f37db397eb956b.js  80.2 kB
  ├ chunks/webpack-d9b18d1ebe7710ba.js     1.8 kB
  └ css/468f1f77e9bfb58c.css               3.76 kB

λ  (Server)  server-side renders at runtime (uses getInitialProps or getServerSideProps)

Building a Cloud Function to run this application. This is needed due to:
 • non-static route /api/mock
 • non-static route /api/statement
 • non-static route /auth/login
 • non-static route /auth/forgot-pass
 • non-static route /auth/confirm-sign-up
 • and 4 other reasons, use --debug to see more

npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@2.0.1: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated uglify-es@3.3.9: support for ECMAScript is superseded by `uglify-js` as of v3.13.0

added 2301 packages in 4m

201 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
Converting a function to an endpoint with an invalid memory option
Converting a function to an endpoint with an invalid memory option
Converting a function to an endpoint with an invalid memory option
Converting a function to an endpoint with an invalid memory option
Converting a function to an endpoint with an invalid memory option
Converting a function to an endpoint with an invalid memory option
Converting a function to an endpoint with an invalid memory option
Converting a function to an endpoint with an invalid memory option
Converting a function to an endpoint with an invalid memory option
Converting a function to an endpoint with an invalid memory option
Converting a function to an endpoint with an invalid memory option
Converting a function to an endpoint with an invalid memory option
Converting a function to an endpoint with an invalid memory option
Converting a function to an endpoint with an invalid memory option
Converting a function to an endpoint with an invalid memory option
Converting a function to an endpoint with an invalid memory option
Converting a function to an endpoint with an invalid memory option
Converting a function to an endpoint with an invalid memory option
i  hosting: The following function(s) are pinned to site possible-fabric-320701 and will be deployed as well: ssrpossiblefabric320701

=== Deploying to 'possible-fabric-320701'...

i  deploying functions, hosting
i  functions: preparing codebase firebase-frameworks-possible-fabric-320701 for deployment
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: Loaded environment variables from .env.
i  functions: preparing .firebase/possible-fabric-320701/functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged /home/manas/techwondoe/ruralco-customer-portal/.firebase/possible-fabric-320701/functions (13.14 MB) for uploading
i  functions: ensuring required API run.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API eventarc.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API pubsub.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API storage.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  functions: required API run.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API storage.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API pubsub.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API eventarc.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: generating the service identity for pubsub.googleapis.com...
i  functions: generating the service identity for eventarc.googleapis.com...
✔  functions: .firebase/possible-fabric-320701/functions folder uploaded successfully
i  hosting[possible-fabric-320701]: beginning deploy...
i  hosting[possible-fabric-320701]: found 40 files in .firebase/possible-fabric-320701/hosting
✔  hosting[possible-fabric-320701]: file upload complete
i  functions: updating Node.js 18 function firebase-frameworks-possible-fabric-320701:ssrpossiblefabric320701(us-west1)...
✔  functions[firebase-frameworks-possible-fabric-320701:ssrpossiblefabric320701(us-west1)] Successful update operation.
Function URL (firebase-frameworks-possible-fabric-320701:ssrpossiblefabric320701(us-west1)): https://ssrpossiblefabric320701-q7wfoxk4uq-uw.a.run.app
i  functions: cleaning up build files...
i  hosting[possible-fabric-320701]: finalizing version...
✔  hosting[possible-fabric-320701]: version finalized
i  hosting[possible-fabric-320701]: releasing new version...
✔  hosting[possible-fabric-320701]: release complete

✔  Deploy complete!

Project Console: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/possible-fabric-320701/overview
Hosting URL: https://possible-fabric-320701.web.app
```

Console:
[image]

Network Tab:

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.